# How to catch a MessagingException on Apache Axis

Tags: java, exception, axis

On my Axis 1.4 webservice this exception is thrown when an incoming message is corrupted.

```
WARN ;2010-07-15 14:45:38,232;org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl;;Exception:
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: javax.mail.MessagingException: Error in input stream;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: End of stream encountered before final boundary marker.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.mail.MessagingException: Error in input stream;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: End of stream encountered before final boundary marker.
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetHeaders.load(InternetHeaders.java:361)
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetHeaders.&lt;init&gt;(InternetHeaders.java:310)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.MultiPartRelatedInputStream.readTillFound(MultiPartRelatedInputStream.java:499)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.MultiPartRelatedInputStream.readAll(MultiPartRelatedInputStream.java:433)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.MultiPartRelatedInputStream.getAttachments(MultiPartRelatedInputStream.java:439)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl.mergeinAttachments(AttachmentsImpl.java:171)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl.getAttachmentCount(AttachmentsImpl.java:550)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getAttachments(Message.java:689)
    at prg.xft.in.attachments.ExtractAttachments.extract(ExtractAttachments.java:45)
    at prg.xft.ib.In.inbound(In.java:79)
    at prg.xft.ib.In.&lt;init&gt;(In.java:54)
    at prg.skel.jiz.ServiceImpl.inbound(ServiceImpl.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: End of stream encountered before final boundary marker.
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.BoundaryDelimitedStream.read(BoundaryDelimitedStream.java:308)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.BoundaryDelimitedStream.read(BoundaryDelimitedStream.java:358)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.BoundaryDelimitedStream.read(BoundaryDelimitedStream.java:370)
    at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:84)
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetHeaders.load(InternetHeaders.java:338)
    ... 42 more
```

I tried to catch the exception multiple times on different places in my source code, but I can not catch it.
The stacktrace only appears in my logs.

Comment: Is prg.xft one of your packages?

Comment: Yes, these are my packages, I tried to catch the exception in one of my classes, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that exception is caught within this class and apache logger prints stack trace. That is common practice. You will be not able to catch it.

See source code for sure:
http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/axis/attachments/AttachmentsImpl.java.htm