# Implementation of Apache axis on Jboss with SQL server

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, jboss, axis

I am facing this problem when trying to get content using axis:

```
ERROR org.apache.axis.client.Call  - Exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: End of stream encountered before final boundary marker.AxisFault

 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException

faultSubcode: 

faultString: java.io.IOException: End of stream encountered before final boundary marker.

faultActor: 

 faultNode: 

faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.io.IOException: End of stream encountered before final boundary marker.



    at org.apache.axis.attachments.BoundaryDelimitedStream.read(BoundaryDelimitedStream.java:308)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.BoundaryDelimitedStream.read(BoundaryDelimitedStream.java:358)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.ManagedMemoryDataSource.&lt;init&gt;(ManagedMemoryDataSource.java:146)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.MultiPartRelatedInputStream.readTillFound(MultiPartRelatedInputStream.java:557)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.MultiPartRelatedInputStream.readAll(MultiPartRelatedInputStream.java:433)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.MultiPartRelatedInputStream.getAttachments(MultiPartRelatedInputStream.java:439)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl.mergeinAttachments(AttachmentsImpl.java:171)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl.getAttachmentByReference(AttachmentsImpl.java:341)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.getObjectByRef(DeserializationContext.java:617)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.JAFDataHandlerDeserializer.populateDataHandler(JAFDataHandlerDeserializer.java:74)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.JAFDataHandlerDeserializer.onStartChild(JAFDataHandlerDeserializer.java:95)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2506)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2405)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1816)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleActivate(AbstractHyperlink.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleMouseUp(AbstractHyperlink.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.access$1(AbstractHyperlink.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink$4.handleEvent(AbstractHyperlink.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:928)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3348)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:2968)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:1930)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:1894)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:localhost

java.io.IOException: End of stream encountered before final boundary marker.
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.MultiPartRelatedInputStream.readTillFound(MultiPartRelatedInputStream.java:609)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.MultiPartRelatedInputStream.readAll(MultiPartRelatedInputStream.java:433)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.MultiPartRelatedInputStream.getAttachments(MultiPartRelatedInputStream.java:439)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl.mergeinAttachments(AttachmentsImpl.java:171)
    at org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl.getAttachmentByReference(AttachmentsImpl.java:341)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.getObjectByRef(DeserializationContext.java:617)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.JAFDataHandlerDeserializer.populateDataHandler(JAFDataHandlerDeserializer.java:74)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.JAFDataHandlerDeserializer.onStartChild(JAFDataHandlerDeserializer.java:95)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2506)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2405)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1816) 
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleActivate(AbstractHyperlink.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleMouseUp(AbstractHyperlink.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.access$1(AbstractHyperlink.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink$4.handleEvent(AbstractHyperlink.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:928)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3348)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:2968)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:1930)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:1894)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)
```

The issue happens when my application is running on Jboss with "SQL server" but works fine with oracle db.

Is axis implementation is any db specific? I have placed all the axis jars in the lib folder.

Can anyone suggest?
Thank You.

Comment: Axis is not really dependent on what database you are using. But, the way a given database return responses is different. So, you might need to make adjustments to your code accordingly.

Comment: This post may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255669/how-to-catch-a-messagingexception-on-apache-axis